# ffmpeg can't find shared library on Asustor

Tags: ffmpeg, asustor

On Asustor installing `ffmpeg` (from App Central in the web interface) puts it in `/volume1/.@plugins/AppCentral/ffmpeg` (with executables in `bin` and libraries in `lib`).

But typing the command `ffmpeg` from the command line issues the error `ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopencore-amrnb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. (This happens for root or non-root user.)

Yet the library **is present** in `lib` and ldd does find it (`ldd /volume1/.@plugins/AppCentral/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg` says: `libopencore-amrnb.so.0 => /volume1/.@plugins/AppCentral/ffmpeg/lib/libopencore-amrnb.so.0 (0x00007f62b2c39000)`).

For the record, `libopencore-amrnb.so.0` is actually a symlink to `libopencore-amrnb.so.0.0.3`, and there are no other instances of either on the system but the ones in `lib`.

Why does ffmpeg say there is "no such file" while there obviously is? And how can one fix this?